# Store certain bits from one register into certain bits of another register

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I am trying to learn computer organization in order to be prepared for an upcoming semester and I stumbled across this problem. The problem asks to store bits 5 to 10 from register $1 into bits 10 to 15 of register $2 without changing $1 and remaining bits of $2. Note: It also says that bit numbering is little endian.

So here is what I did.

```
sll $3, $1, 22    
slr $3, $3, 27
sll $3, $3, 10    # after last 3 steps $3 should have desired bits from $1 in bits 10 to 
                  # 15, and the rest of its bits should be 0`s.
or $2, $2, $3
```

Now my question is, does the endianness affect the code that I came up with ? Is this code correct for what the problem asks for ?

Small remark, I forgot to set the bits 10 to 15 of register 2 to 0`s before I or it, but I know that it is neccecery.

Comment: Unless you store words to memory and then read back as bytes or something like that, endianness doesn't matter.  A left shift is *always* a multiply by two of the whole register.  I didn't read the full problem yet, so IDK about the other part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you have to transport a block of bits from a source to a destination the procedure is always the same and can be described by three parameters:

1. **SRC_MASK**
   A value the source operand is ANDed with.
2. **SRC_SHIFT**
   How much to shift the source operand. Actually this should also specify a direction, either left of right. We will assume left shift here.
   Within CPU that natively support rotate operations, we can use them to get rid of the need for a direction.
3. **DST_MASK**
   A value the destination operand is ANDed with.

The algorithm is then

```
dst = (dst & DST_MASK) | (src & SRC_MASK) << SRC_SHIFT;
```

---

This is a general algorithm, specific instances can lead to specific optimizations, as a trivial example consider the moving of all the bits, which is a simple "move".

Since in general the masks have the size of the registers, in MIPS this requires the classic use of the `lui`/`ori` pair.
Alternatively we can, as you did, use shifts to mask out the non relevant bits of the source operand, however this doesn't work for clearing a non continuous block of bits in the destination (and in fact you haven't).

In MIPS the C code above is then:

```
lui $t0, SRC_MASK >> 16
ori $t0, SRC_MASK & 0xffff     ;t0 = SRC_MASK

lui $t1, DST_MASK >> 16
ori $t1, DST_MASK & 0xffff     ;t1 = DST_MASK

and $t2, $1, $t0               ;t2 = src & SRC_MASK
sll $t2, SRC_SHIFT             ;t2 = (src & SRC_MASK) << SRC_SHIFT

and $2, $2, $t1                ;$2 = dst & DST_MASK
or $2, $2, $t2                 ;$2 = (dst & DST_MASK) |  (src & SRC_MASK) << SRC_SHIFT
```

For the problem in question, the values of the masks and the shift amount are:

> SRC_MASK = 0x000007e0h
>   SRC_SHIFT = 5
>   SRC_MASK = 0xffff03ffh

---

### A word about endianness

I don't like the word "endianness" for ordering bits, it is too much related to [byte ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Big-endian) instead.

Given a word, we can label its bits in two ways:

```
31     23     17     7      0        0      7      15     24      31
+------+------+------+------+        +------+------+------+------+  
|                           |        |                           |
+------+------+------+------+        +------+------+------+------+

       Little endian                           Big endian
```

This is a convention that is useful for human, from a CPU perspective there is no such thing as "bit endianess" since registers just hold a set of, either way, ordered bit, not numbers: it is the software that gives these sets a meaning.

So the problem is mentioning "little endian" just to clarify that the author had in mind the left labeling when speaking of bits.

Simply put, the question "*Given the number 12345, which one is the 2nd digit?*" is not universally answered as "*4*" some people with little mathematical background tend to answer "*2*". Also they tend to confuse the "*second digit*", which is 4, with the "*digit with index/position 2*" which is "*3*" (because indexing starts from 0 and there is no 0th place).

To avoid all these misunderstanding the author cleared out that what they mean, although, in my opinion, using a bad terminology.

Personally I refer to the labeling on the left as "natural ordering" (since to set bit *X* we OR with 2<sup>X</sup>) and to the labeling on the right as "reverse ordering".