# Extract four bits from a number and insert into another number in MIPS

Tags: mips32

Write the shortest sequence of MIPS instructions that extracts four bits, bit
18 to bit 15, from register `$s1` and uses the value of this field to replace bits 12 to 9 in
register `$s2` without changing other bits of register `$s2`.

So far, I came up with:

```
srl $s1, $s1, 15 #remove bits 0 to 14
sll $s1, $s1, 28 #remove bits 31 to 19
andi $t0, $s2, 0 # setting register $t0 to 0
srl $t0, $t0, 13 # remove bits 0 to 13
sll $t0, $21, 13 # adds $s1, to $t0
or $s2, $s2, $t0 # replaces bits
```

I know this is wrong, but I can't figure out an efficient way to solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store certain bits from one register into certain bits of another register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045665/store-certain-bits-from-one-register-into-certain-bits-of-another-register)